# Bug in select component from Material UI v1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need some help =)

I'm using Material UI V1 beta, I'm populating data into a DropDown menu, the WS I'm using is working fine, I can see the first option from my WS in the Dropdown menu but when I try to select a different option I'm getting an error in the console and don't know what it is and why.

Don't know if I'm missing something but this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'material-ui/Select';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/Menu';

export default class ExampleDD extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      description: '',
      descriptionError: '',
      DivisionData: [],
      DivisionState: ''

    };
    this.renderDivisionOptions = this.renderDivisionOptions.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeDivision = this.handleChangeDivision.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const divisionWS = 'http://localhost:8080/services/Divisions/getAll';

    fetch(divisionWS)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          DivisionData: findResponse,
          DivisionState: findResponse[0].divDeptShrtDesc
        });
      });


  }

  handleChangeDivision(event){
    this.setState({ DivisionState: event.target.value });
  }

  renderDivisionOptions() {
    return this.state.DivisionData.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={i}
          value={dt.divDeptShrtDesc}>
          {dt.divDeptShrtDesc}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.DivisionState}
        onChange={this.handleChangeDivision}
      >
        {this.renderDivisionOptions()}
      </Select>
    )}
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Some help will be nice.

Regards,

Comment: what error do you get then?

Comment: Sorry, I just update the question with a screenshot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MenuItem` is a named export, use `import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';`